# Ajax Success Returning Commented Html Tag

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, select

I am trying to set up a select box that would show up the cities depending on the prior selection of the state.

Basically, I am using ajax to run my php.file to populate my `<option>`. In the php file I successfully passed the pre-selected state to query the database. However, now, to populate the `<option>` I am using ajax success to call the php file, however, whenever I try to pass the variable containing the php code it shows up commented with `!--` and `--`.

```
//  hmtl

<select id="select-city" required >
<option disabled selected>Selecione sua Cidade</option>
</select>
```

```
// js code

function fillSelectCity () {

    var getState = document.getElementById('selectState');
    var stateID = getState.options[getState.selectedIndex].value;

    $.ajax ({
    type: "POST", 
    url: "fillcity.php",
    data: { stateID : stateID },
    success:  function (){

        var phpfile = "'fillcity.php'"
        var tag = "<?php include_once " + phpfile + " ?>";
        $('#select-city').html(tag);
/// here the output is "<!-- ?php include_once 'fillcity.php' ? -->"
    }    
    })

 }
```

```
//php file

<?php 

$conn = mysqli_connect("host", "user", "pass", "db");

if(isset($_POST['stateID']))
{
    $stateID = $_POST['stateID'];
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM states WHERE stateID = '$stateID'"; 
$result_one = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_one); //my table has a specific ID for each state, so I am fetching the acronoym of the state according to the id;
$stateUf = $row['uf']; // passing the acronym to the $stateUf
mysqli_free_result($result_one);

$queryCity = "SELECT * FROM city WHERE Uf = '$stateUf'"; //query all cities with the acronym

if ($result = mysqli_query($conn, $queryCity)){
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $id = $row['cityID'];
        $name =  $row['cityName'];
        $name = utf8_encode($name);
        echo <<< EOT
        "<option value="$id">$name</option>"
EOT;
    }

    mysqli_free_result($result);}

    else {echo "<option>Error</option>";}


?>
```

I expect to populate my select options by looping through the table `city` in the php file. The tag `<?php include_once 'fillcity.php' ?>` was used to populate the state select. Probably, there may be a more direct way to populate accordingly, but as I am new to programming, I am trying to figure things out on my own. But please, feel free to recommend other methods as I am not sure if what I am planning to do will gonna work. Thanks!

Comment: You can't use JavaScript variables in PHP code. JavaScript runs on the client after the PHP script finishes.

Comment: If the `fillSelectCity` function isn't in a `.php` file, `<?php` will not be executed by PHP, it will be treated as a JavaScript literal.

Comment: That's why you're getting a comment, you're putting `<?php` into your HTML, and it's not a valid HTML tag.

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this one. You can modify it later for improvement.**

**read.php**

```
<?php
    //include header
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
$conn= mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$type = $_GET["type"];
if($type == "GetState"){
    //SAMPLE QUERY
    $sql = "SELECT StateID,StateName from State";
    $data = array();
    $results = $db -> query($sql);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)){
        $data[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
}
if($type == "GetCity"){
    $StateID= $_POST["StateID"];
    //SAMPLE QUERY
    //LET'S ASSUME THAT YOU HAVE FOREIGN KEY
    $sql = "SELECT CityID,CityName from City where StateID = '".$StateID."'";
    $data = array();
    $results = $db -> query($sql);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)){
        $data[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
}
?>
```

**index.html**

```
<select id="state"></select>
<select id="city"></select>

<!--PLEASE INCLUDE JQUERY RIGHT HERE E.G. <script src='jquery.min.js'></script>--> 
<!--DOWNLOAD JQUERY HERE https://jquery.com/-->
<script>
    LoadState();
    function LoadState(){
        $.ajax({
            url:"read.php?type=GetState",
            type:"GET",
            success:function(data){
                var options = "<option selected disabled value="">Select 
State</option>";
            for(var i in data){
                options += "<option value='"+data[i].StateID+"'>" + data[i].StateName+ "</option>";
            }
            $("#state").html(options);
        }
    });
}
function LoadCity(StateID){
    $.ajax({
        url:"read.php?type=GetCity",
        type:"POST",
        data:{
            StateID: StateID
        },
        success:function(data){
            var options = "<option selected disabled value="">Select City</option>";
            for(var i in data){
                options += "<option value='"+data[i].CityID+"'>" + data[i].CityName+ "</option>";
            }
            $("#city").html(options);
        }
    });
}
$("#city").change(function(){
    LoadCity(this.value);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to `include 'fillcity.php`. The AJAX call runs that script, and the response is the output. It will be in the parameter of the success function.

```
function fillSelectCity () {

    var getState = $("#selectState").val();

    $.ajax ({
        type: "POST", 
        url: "fillcity.php",
        data: { stateID : stateID },
        success:  function (tag){
            $('#select-city').html(tag);
        }    
    });

 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! I actually just read and I tried that, and it worked with a minor issue. Thanks again!